# Distribution of a Random Variable chosen by coinflip.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I flip a fair coin once and if I get heads I have $X\sim Normal(0,1)$ and at tails $X\sim Normal(0,2)$.

I want to derive the CDF of $X$.

My thoughts:

Let $Y$ be my random variable representing a coinflip, mapping Heads to 0 and Tails to 1 where $P(Y=0)=P(Y=1)=1/2$.

Then by law of total probability:

$P(X\leq x)=P(X\leq x \ \cap Y = 0) +P(X\leq x \ \cap Y =1)$

And then by conditional probability:
$P(X\leq x) = P(Y = 0)P(X\leq x | Y =0)+P(Y=1)P(X\leq x|Y = 1)$

So then:

$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x) = \frac{1}{2}F_{N(0,1)}(x)+\frac{1}{2}F_{N(0,2)}(x)$

Comment: Your work is fine. Note also that $F_{N(0,2)}(x) = F_{N(0,1)}(x/\sqrt{2})$.